# Screen size in FreeBSD in VirtualBox

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox, console, monitors

I am installing FreeBSD 10.0 on VirtualBox, and I can't figure out how to change the size of my screan, in the virtualbox?

The freebsd in the virtualbox treats my screen like it's 1/4th the size of my actual screen?

[image: screenshot]

I want it to fill my screen without the text and images expanding.

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions?

Comment: @eyoung100 The VirtualBox Guest Additions is only relevant for increasing the screen size when using Xorg. Guest Additions does not resize the virtual console.

Answer (score 5):

use vidcontrol MODE_xxx

For example to have a screen 1024x768x24, in the console :

```
# vidcontrol MODE_280
```

To know which mode you can be interested in, in the console :

```
# vidcontrol -i mode
```

The left column gives you the number you have to put after MODE_

Comment: is there a way to make this setting permanent?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274979/128489

Comment: For `vidcontrol -i mode` to list any modes, one must be using the `sc` console driver instead of `vt`. To use `sc` instead of `vt`, add `kern.vty=sc` to `/boot/loader.conf` and reboot.

Answer (score 3):

To make the console mode permanent, add a line to /etc/rc.conf:

```
allscreens_flags="MODE_332"
```

(substitute your desired mode number for 332 of course.)

Answer (score 0):

use Scaled Mode in VirtualBox (View -> Scaled Mode), this will fill the entire screen (regardless of what mode you set using vidcontrol in your FreeBSD box).

Comment: The OP said "I want it to fill my screen without the text and images expanding. " , your answer sounds like it will exactly do that.

Comment: Using just vidcontrol is not enough, you should combine setting screen mode and changing to Scaled Mode - it will give a desirable effect.